# When will (or won't) updateViewConstraints be called on my view controller for me by the framework?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view controller and I want to craete and set my view constraints in updateViewConstraints.
I have a break point in that method and it's never getting called.

Why might it not be getting called?
When will the framework want to call this method on my view controller?

Answer (score 17):

`updateViewConstraints` is called by `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (via your view's `layoutSubviews` method along the way). As the name suggests, this is called whenever your view controller needs to update its layout.

If you finding that `updateViewConstraints` is *never* being called then you should make sure that you are calling `super` your view controller's methods where required.

Also, it sounds as if you are *creating* your constraints inside `updateViewConstraints`? That may also be the cause of your problem. You should be updating your constraints in that method, not creating them (in the same way that in `layoutSubviews` you position your views, but don't instantiate them).

Comment: I'm still not sure why updateViewConstraints doesn't get called on some of my view controllers... i'm not sure when to expect it will get called or when it won't.

Comment: Are you *definitely* adding your view constraints outside of `updateViewConstraints` (i.e, in `viewDidLoad` or similar).

Comment: Documentation says "You may override this method in a subclass in order to add constraints to the view or its subviews.". So it seems totally cool to create constraints in updateConstraints: in case when you need to drastically change your interface.

Comment: @lxt,Thanks for your perfect answer which really solve me at my uiscrollview issue.

Comment: This answer pointed out to me that I wasn't calling super in `viewWillTransition:toSize:withCoordinator` and was therefore not receiving an `updateViewConstraints` call in certain cases.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can add constraints in `updateViewConstraints` if you add a flag to indicate whether constraints have been added. Refer to my [gist](https://gist.github.com/acalism/d4414af29e55dbc6fc778aecfbb8bdd7)

Comment: The documentation says "The default implementation of this method does nothing." for viewWillLayoutSubviews() so as of 2019, does not seem like it is called FYI.

Comment: updateViewConstraints is called by viewWillLayoutSubviews - it not true.

Answer (score 15):

You are in ViewController and you want the system to call `updateViewConstraints`, then you have to call this

```
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

Comment: In my case I added myView as a direct subview of self.view. Since self.view is not auto layout enabled by default, [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints] doesn't work but [self.myView setNeedsUpdateConstraints] works - triggering updateConstraints method of myView.

Comment: If you call it in `viewDidLoad`, `updateViewConstraints` will be called **twice** in Xcode 9. So, I think Klaas's answer is better.

Answer (score 14):

Your `UIView` must implement `+ (BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout` and return `YES`. In that case `updateViewConstraints` will be initially called to setup constraints.

Comment: From what I can tell this is nearly correct. If the UIView (or one of its subviews) of the UIViewController returns TRUE for + requiresConstraintBasedLayout then the view controller will participate in auto layout setup by calling -updateViewConstraints.

Answer (score 7):

Just a guess and not 100% certain:

updateViewConstraints won't be called if your view controllers root view does not require auto layout. So you have to at least add one constraint to your root view (somewhere in loadview or viewDidLoad) or set

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

This should trigger your break point.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. No need to call the setNeedsUpdateConstraints. when the view loads updateViewConstraints should automatically get called. Further we can create constraints in updateViewConstraints, its not limited only to update constraints.

Comment: @posha I DO agree with you. `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` make `updateViewConstraints` called twice.

Comment: One more thing, if the view controller is presented, your code will make its view's size is `CGSizeZero`. You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints in `updateViewConstraints` if you add a flag to indicate whether constraints have been added. See also [my gist](https://gist.github.com/acalism/d4414af29e55dbc6fc778aecfbb8bdd7)

```
@implementation ViewController {    
    bool _constraintsAdded;
}
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    if (!_constraintsAdded) {
        _constraintsAdded = true;

        // TODO: add constraints to self.view's subviews
    }

    NSLog(@"update constraint.");
    // TODO: update constraints needed

    [super updateViewConstraints]; // must be called finally.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` as the Apple documentaion says:

> To schedule a change, call setNeedsUpdateConstraints on the view. The system then calls your implementation of updateViewConstraints before the layout occurs.
>   ([Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621379-updateviewconstraints?language=objc))